# How do I increase allocated memory in jvm for Grails commands on IntelliJ IDEA 9 Beta?

Tags: java, grails, intellij-idea

I use Windows Vista , 4GB RAM , Core2

I have tested with this idea.exe.vmoptions  :
-Xms64m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-ea
-agentlib:yjpagent=disablej2ee,disablecounts,disablealloc,sessionname=IntelliJIdea90

Answer (score 1):

The `-Xmx256M` option is hardcoded at the moment and there is no way to change it. There is a [related discussion](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/270712) in the IDEA forum. If you need a way to specify heap size, please [file a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Answer (score 1):

Stupid I am : I have found on run configuration VM parameters and I have set "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx1024M -server"